# ArcPy publish large map throws ERROR 001269: Compressing the service definition failed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, map-service

I have a .mxd file with more than 1.3 million features that I would like to publish as ArcGIS map service using Python.

When I publish the map manually from ArcMap, it works fine and it appears in ArcCatalog. However, I have to use arcpy since this process needs to be invoked regularly every few days.

I use the arcpy functions `arcpy.StageService_server()` and `arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server()`.

This raises the following error:

```
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.7\ArcPy\arcpy\server.py", line 1405, in StageService
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 001269: Compressing the service definition failed.
Failed to execute (StageService).
```

When I run the same code with a smaller mxd file on the same system, it works fine. Also, some people mention that this might appear when using 64 bit Python. I checked this, it is running in 32 bit mode. So my guess is that the error is raised because of the amount of features (>1.3 million).

How could I avoid this error? Or is there a possibility to split up the mxd file programmatically and then merge the published map services?

Comment: I publish maps based on hundreds of millions of features, and they take just seconds. The number of features shouldn't matter at all, just the number of layers (unless you've failed to register the source with the server, but that violates best practice).

Comment: Ok, thanks. The map has 256 layers.

Comment: Hmmm. That's quite a few layers. I often have scores, but they're scale dependent and only 3-5 draw at any one time.  Merging published map services is generally a mistake, but drawing layers over a basemap is best practice. But neither of those is related to your error (nor is feature count).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of using Python right off he bat, use the Share as a Service wizard in ArcCatalog. Then Analyze the service. Your scripting does no analyzing. Then when it completes right click the results in the results panel and copy python snippet, then you'll have the script that can be run over and over. If it doesn't run, then clear up the errors that appear in the error panel.

Also, I found this solution on ESri's site:

> 001269: Compressing the service definition failed.
>
> Description
>
> The tool could not compress the folder containing the service
>   definition into a service definition file.
>
> Solution Make sure you are not accessing files in the folder
>   containing the service definition.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Where can I find the python snippet?

Comment: Under the geoprocessing menu, in arcmap, there is a results panel (about 10 items down in the list). If you click results from that list it will open a pane that says Current Session, Shared.   All geoprocessing tools that you run in Catalog have results in the results panel under Current sessions. All results under Current Sessions, can be right clicked and a pyhon snippet can be copied and then pasted into notepad or desired editor.